# linux curl 301 redirect when posting form data

Tags: linux, redirect, curl, http-post

I am writing a simple linux shell script to post form data and collect the response and I am getting a moved permanently 301 redirect.

Here is my script:

authenticates and saves session cookie

```
 curl -c cookie.txt -d "username=uname" -d "password=psword" site.com/user/do_login
```

uses authenticated session, set to handle redirs, changes user agent to mobile, then sends post request

```
 curl -b cookie.txt --max-redirs 10 -A "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A293 Safari/6531.22.7" --data "start=2013-11-11" site.com/account/location/
```

This results with the 301 redirect, any thoughts or corrections would be much appreciated!

Note: i am using http:// infront of my URLs this form wont let me post a full url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that by removing the / at the end of location in my url and by using -d instead of --data it resolved my issue also removed the --max-redirs 10.